# Why "__KERNEL_DS" is needed in x86 Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

(Sorry for poor English...)

I have two questions.

1. In the x86 Linux, I know that the CS is important because of CPU privilege level. But, I don't know why the DS should be two also.(__USER_DS, __KERNEL_DS).

   I confused because the only difference between user data segment and kernel data segment is the "DPL". And it doesn't matter because kernel code runs with CPL 0. (Am I wrong?)

   So, I wonder why the kernel have to change the data segment also when the mode is changed between the user mode and the kernel mode.

   In other words, I think the only one data segment selector is enough in flat memory model. What's the meaning of DPL of data segment selector in flat memory model?
2. To prevent user mode code accessing the kernel space(for example, like "mov $eax, DS:*0xc1000000"), which mechanism is used? segmentation or paging?

   I think the user code can addressing the kernel space because the user data segment includes the kernel area. So, It must be the paging mechanism who block the such access. right? Could you explain more detail?

Thank you in advance.